# MySQL insert new rows and ignore existing rows, based in many columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table where I want to insert new rows like

```
ID   |  MAGICID |  PERSONREF |  DATA
1    |        1 |    0000010 |  any trash data
2    |        1 |    0000011 |  any trash data
3    |        1 |    0000012 |  any trash data
4    |        1 |    0000013 |  any trash data
5    |        2 |    0000010 |  any trash data
6    |        2 |    0000011 |  any trash data
7    |        2 |    0000012 |  any trash data
8    |        2 |    0000013 |  any trash data
9    |        3 |    0000010 |  any trash data
10   |        3 |    0000011 |  any trash data
11   |        3 |    0000012 |  any trash data
12   |        3 |    0000013 |  any trash data
```

In table `ID` is a PK with `INT(10)`, `MAGICID` is a `FOREIGN KEY` to another TABLE with `INT(10)` , `PERSONREF` is a normal column with `VARCHAR(8)`

For me, **a duplicate row is when** `MAGICID` and `PERSONREF` is same

```
ID   |  MAGICID |  PERSONREF |  DATA   ---Table without duplicates, is OK
1    |        1 |    0000010 |  any trash data
2    |        1 |    0000011 |  any trash data
```

_

```
ID   |  MAGICID |  PERSONREF |  DATA   ---Table with duplicates, is bad
1    |        1 |    0000010 |  any trash data
2    |        1 |    0000010 |  any trash data
```

A insert should work like this

```
-- table before insert
ID   |  MAGICID |  PERSONREF |  DATA
1    |        1 |    0000010 |  any trash data
2    |        1 |    0000011 |  any trash data
3    |        1 |    0000012 |  any trash data
4    |        2 |    0000015 |  any trash data
```

The inserts

```
INSERT .... (1 , '0000010' ,'trash')
INSERT .... (1 , '0000011' ,'trash')
INSERT .... (1 , '0000012' ,'trash')
INSERT .... (1 , '0000015' ,'trash')
INSERT .... (1 , '0000016' ,'trash') -- in each procces MAGIC is the same for all inserts
```

After look...

```
ID   |  MAGICID |  PERSONREF |  DATA
1    |        1 |    0000010 |  any trash data
2    |        1 |    0000011 |  any trash data
3    |        1 |    0000012 |  any trash data
4    |        2 |    0000015 |  any trash data
41   |        1 |    0000015 |  trash --beacuse is new for this MAGICID ,ID is simulated :)
42   |        1 |    0000016 |  trash --beacuse is new for this MAGICID, ID is simulated :)
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a [`UNIQUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/constraint-primary-key.html) constraint over the composite `(MAGICID, PERSONREF)`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE myTable ADD UNIQUE (MAGICID, PERSONREF);
   ```
2. Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

   ```
   INSERT INTO myTable
     (MAGICID, PERSONREF, DATA)
   VALUES
     (1, '0000010', 'trash'),
     (1, '0000011', 'trash'),
     (1, '0000012', 'trash'),
     (1, '0000015', 'trash'),
     (1, '0000016', 'trash')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     DATA = DATA
   ;
   ```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a586f/1/0).

Comment: i suppose that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  DATA = VALUES(DATA)` was update `DATA`, but  I want keep the old, I only remove this to do it?

Comment: @jasilva: Oh.  My misunderstanding.  You still need to specify at least one column to update, but could just set whichever you like to itself e.g. `... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DATA = DATA`.  An alternative would be to do `INSERT IGNORE ...` after defining the `UNIQUE` key, and not worry about `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, however that will ignore *all* errors—not just duplicate key errors—so could lead to unintended consequences.  See [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/548570) for more information.

Comment: Ok no problem, this a great answer for me, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

For this example your gave, `INSERT .... (1 , '0000010' ,'trash')`, you would have to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (MAGICID , PERSONREF, DATA) 
SELECT 1, '0000010', 'trash' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID
                FROM you_table
                WHERE MAGICID = 1 AND PERSONREF = '0000010')
```

This will basically insert 1, '0000010', 'trash' if the combination of MAGICID and PERSONREF is unique